# Run Custom Script Extension Against Azure App Service

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation

I am able to execute Custom Script Extensions against VMs using Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension and noticed that Azure App Services have Extensions listed as one of their options:

> Extensions add functionality to your App Service. Click add to see the
>   list of available extensions.

What I would like to achieve is running some PowerShell against the VM hosting an App Service, but can't locate a Resource Manager cmdlet like Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension. An example is modifying the security of some of the directories of IIS hosting my website to disable anonymous access, and adding a few files to directories of my website. I am able to achieve this using a script against an IaaS Azure VM and am wondering if this will work against an App Service, and if so, how to target the VM of the App Service.

Key actions I take as part of this PowerShell is:

1. Disable anonymous access to certain directories in IIS
2. Limit access to certain file types
3. Edit existing XML files
4. Add new files to a directory (downloaded via CDN)

Logging into the Kudu interface (Mysite.scm.azure...) I am able to execute some PowerShell via the debug Console option, so I am thinking there has to be a way to run PowerShell via Azure Automation beyond the AzureRm.Websites cmdlets as with the Kudu PowerShell interface I was able to create directories with a plain old create-item cmdlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Service is very different from VM hosting. In App Service, you never get direct access to the VM, and there is generally no way that you can run any script that affects the VM at a global level.

Instead, you are only able to affect the files that make up the Web App, and everything runs under a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

Comment: Affecting the files in the Web App is one of my core requirements. How is this best achieved? Ex. Create an extension that adds the desired files. My plan is to execute this via Azure Automation

Comment: You can use the Kudu vfs or zip API to upload files to your web app. You should be able to call that from Azure automation

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Any ideas about how to modify IIS or run PowerShell commands via Azure Automation given that I can execute these in the Kudu debug console? (I have updated my original post with details)

Comment: Kudu console only runs things inside the sandbox, and can never be used for permanent site configuration (other than uploading files). See all the `*RmWebApp*` PowerShell to see what you can change. Start with `Set-AzureRmWebApp`.

Comment: What about a Webjob? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2014/01/22/running-powershell-web-jobs-on-azure-websites/

Comment: WebJobs support running PowerShell. But if you want to talk to Azure, you'll need to set up a Service Principal.

Comment: So per IIS access, I don't see a way to disable anonymous access for particular directories. Since this is sandboxed, are there any options (ex. ApplicationHost.xdt)

Comment: And per the upload. If I store my .zip file in Blob Storage, is that acceptable. Using your REST Example, do you have an example of how best to upload a Zip file from Azure Blob Storage? https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API